# Получение строки из базы данных подобно Firestore

Tags: java, android

Я решил перейти с Firestore на phpMyAdmin, столкнулся с проблемой, раньше чтобы получить определённую строку из БД Firestore я писал следующее

```
FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            DocumentReference documentReference2 = firebaseFirestore.collection("InformationEN").document(itemTasksAdapter.get(position).getid());
            documentReference2.get().addOnCompleteListener(task ->
            {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = task.getResult();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("id", documentSnapshot.getString("id"));
                    MainActivity.curFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                }
            });
```

Таким образом я получал в `Bundle` нужную строку из БД Firestore, но как сделать тоже самое из БД phpMyAdmin мне не понятно, я написал следующий код

```
ApiInterfaceInformationEN apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterfaceInformationEN.class);
            Call<ArrayList<ItemInformation>> call = apiInterface.getContact("InformationEN", itemTasksAdapter.get(position).getid());
            call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<ItemInformation>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ArrayList<ItemInformation>> call, @NonNull Response<ArrayList<ItemInformation>> response) {


                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ArrayList<ItemInformation>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                    MainActivity.Toast("Error\n" + t.toString());
                }
            });
```

Из `ApiClient` я получаю ссылку, а с помощью `ApiInterfaceInformationEN` я указываю нужное слово для определения позиции с нужными данными в БД, осталось как-то получить непосредственно данные, как это сделать?

`ApiInterfaceInformationEN`

```
public interface ApiInterfaceInformationEN {

    @GET("getDataInformationEN.php")
    Call<ArrayList<ItemInformation>> getContact(
            @Query("item_type") String item_type,
            @Query("key") String keyword
    );
}
```

`ApiClient`

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://ссылка/";
    public static Retrofit retrofit;

    public static Retrofit getApiClient(){
        if (retrofit==null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

Comment: данные получены в onResponse, но не обработаны. В чем затруднения не понятно.

Comment: @YuraIvanov Как правильно код написать в onResponse?

Comment: Вы же не написали что у вас возвращается что вам надо передать. это у вас надо спросить что вам надо написать притом правильно... Если с сервром коммуникация написана верно, то у вас есть данные в `response.body()` с типом `ArrayList<ItemInformation>` делайте с ними все что хотите: итерируйте, передавайте в activity... хотя бы начните с лога того, что вам приходит...